# How do I stop certain code from running?

Tags: java

I have a class that "bans" a player, but I don't want that player to be banned if his name is within a string array. I could loop through the length of the array and use booleans, but there has to be an easier way? I saw something that said just put **if** a condition is met, put `return;` and it'll stop all code running below that if statement.

Edit: Thanks for all the help! You were all helpful, even if you're one of the people that downvoted this, which is 4 people at least.

Comment: yes you are right, if..else statement is conditional block, which executes for typical conditions

Comment: Call me old school, I was taught to have one entry and one exit point for all functions/methods, but putting `return` any where other then the end of the method is a bad idea, as it's to easy for people to miss it and mis-understand what the logic is trying to achieve.

Comment: Call me older school, but the compiler transforms methods with multiple return statements into single-exit procedures anyway, *ergo* they are semantically equivalent, *ergo* there is no need to jump through additional hoops to avoid multiple return statements. I've never met this mythical programmer who can't understand them, or the one who can't remember grade 3 operator precedence either. It has always struck me that some programmers must be amazingly contemptuous of their colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method that checks if the player is in the array of Strings and yes if you use `return` in a void method the method will just end.

For example

```
public void returnUsage(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("n doesn't equal 1.");
}
```

But it would probably be best to use an `if` and `else`  to skip the code you don't want to run if the condition is not met. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Please, please, please use curly braces for your if statement; i.e. `if(n==1) { return; }`

Answer (score 0):

An array is the wrong data structure for this task. Add the players to a `Set<> allowedPlayers = new HashSet<String>()` then use `if(allowedPlayers.contains(name)) return;` to conditionally exit the method based on whether the name of the player is in the set. The set will remain fast when the number of names gets large. With an array scanning the array will be slow when the array is big.

Comment: Simpler to just have a Set<String> of banned player names.

Comment: 'The `Set` will remain fast' depends entirely on which implementation you use.

Comment: The array was going to be 2-8 values. Thanks, will switch to a Set.

Comment: @AlexTrevoso if you like my answer please vote it up.